# Nuxt 3 re render component after API response

Tags: components, nuxt.js, vue-component, rendering, nuxtjs3

I am working on nuxt 3 and I need re render component after API response.

```js
<template>
<AssetsTab
   :form-data="formData.assets"
   :loader="loader"
   @on-submit="submitForm"
/>
</template>
<script setup>

onMounted( async () => {
  await getDetails(); //API call
});
</script>
```

Here once the API call `getDetails()` successed. I need to rerender `AssetsTab` component again.

Answer (score 2):

Use a reactive variable like `const isApiRespond = ref(false)` and make the variable true in the getDetails function when you get the successful API response. Then in the template use `v-if` like below,

```
<AssetsTab
   v-if=isApiRespond
   :form-data="formData.assets"
   :loader="loader"
   @on-submit="submitForm"
/>
```

Now if you again want to Re-Render your component then use a `key` prop in your component. Whenever your props value update, the component will auto-update.

```
<AssetsTab
   v-if=isApiRespond
   :key="rerendervalue"
   :form-data="formData.assets"
   :loader="loader"
   @on-submit="submitForm"
/>
```

In above code whenever your key value update the whole component will auto update.

Here is a [VuePlaygroud](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9kcFuwjAMhl/FygXQoBXXrkWbJk27TOI+79AVQwtpEiWBaSp99zkJoGnSplxix/ls//8gHo3JTkcShShdYzvjwZE/mhWqrjfaehjA0hZG2Frdw4RLJ7enJ92blEeR5SEKKBSoUDVaOQ+nWkIVANPl7Jrr3e6SQ/FCUuqEWNeWlEfBdeGUeRqHB+HAU29k7YkjgLJdwkMju+ZQoeAOd9USxWoYInkcy7xdpro4X3GgryrMUTT6qHz6giLnkjK/ccVcpKUWfW2yvdOKFRkCBS8PDkUBMRNycc+CL633xhV57rZNWH7vMm13Od8yy926njJy/eLD6k9HlsFBHYAR1cgtr5L9p75Wr2Fu2vzy4Cqnsdo4FnRD207ROkTTNxRxWRTvs/u4hLphptNZtYp7hP9aUib1jq1oaik7tUs9WrIE1QrFPOKzSAuoMdrzpzno2ZwoPkDy9jnghiEC4HyGyWIy8vbsTrLppwfjN4Cc4Vk=) Link check it's console you will understand.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I need to render the component again not only one time. Initially and also once after the API response. Hope you understand my requirement.

Comment: So you can pass props with some value. Every time the props change the Component will rerender again.

Comment: Okay, It will call the onMounted method if any props are changed?

Comment: Yes it will, Check the answer, I have update the and for again rerender purpose.